# Why does a SyntaxError prevent the previous line from running when a TypeError does not?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
console.log('hello');
console.og('bye');
```

Here "hello" is printed and showing error on second line.

```js
console.log('hello');
console..log('bye');
```

But here, "hello" is not printed while error is in second line.

I know why the second line is throwing an error, but why does that affect the first line?

Comment: javascript is parsed, if it doesn't parse, it doesn't run

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript is not simply interpreted line-by-line. The code will first be parsed and then executed. Your second example has a syntax error where the code simply cannot be parsed, so it will never get to the execution step.

The parsing step is why things like hoisting can work. If your code simply started execution then hoisting would not be possible. If your code was not parsed before execution, you could also do something like this:

```js
function someFunction() {
    console.log('hello');
}

someFunction();
const someVariable = 5;
console.log(someVariable + 10);

---
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed. Amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium.
```

and expect it to work because the code is correct until you get to the lorem ipsum text. However, this clearly does not work for the same reason your second example does not work. The parsing fails.

Your first example is syntactically correct, and will start execution and only throw an error when it reaches the second line.

I recommend reading [this article](https://almogad.medium.com/javascript-is-it-compiled-or-interpreted-9779278468fc). It should explain a few things about JS's behaviour in relation to this topic.